# How do I cast a double to an int?

Tags: c#, types, casting, double, int

I have a program that uses a formula to calculate the refurb on a unit (parts replaced on cableboxes that were damaged) divided by total units (cableboxes that went through refurb, but did not have any parts replaced). I looked up casting online, and the format for it is:

```
int valuetoconvert = Convert.ToInt32;
```

I'm doing that, but I still get the following error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'double to int. An explicit conversion exists(are you missing a cast?)

What am I doing wrong? Can someone please help? Thank you.

Here's some of my code:

```
private int GetRefurbRate()
{
string sql = "";
double Refurb_Rate;
int totalRefurb = 0;
int totalUnits = 0;
string error_msg = "";


sql = "SELECT COUNT(rp.repair_ord) " +
"FROM " + schema + ".repair_part rp " +
"WHERE rp.repair_ord = '" + repair_ord + "' ";
while (true)
{
if (!myDb.RunSql(sql, true))
{
error_msg = "DBError for getting Refurb Rate";
break;
}
if (myDb.dbRdr.HasRows)
{
if (myDb.dbRdr.Read())
{
try //Try and Catch are here b/c I originally had everything ints, and and they just caught the 0 exception.
{

Refurb_Rate = Convert.ToInt32( totalRefurb / totalUnits * 100); //This is where I try to perform the cast.

}
catch (Exception e)
{
Console.WriteLine(e);
}

}

//int Refurb_Rate = Convert.ToInt32(Refurb_Rate);
}

break;
}
myDb.dbRdr.Close();

if (error_msg != String.Empty)
{
MessageBox.Show(error_msg, "Get Refurb Rate",
MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
}
```

Comment: Refurb_Rate = Convert.ToInt32( totalRefurb / totalUnits * 100d);

Comment: ( no C# experience but C, so just a comment ) In C if you write (int) before the variable it will drop the stuff behind the comma. If you want to round it off  you use functions like ceil() and floor() or round()

Answer (score 5):

You say you want an int cast, but you actually need to cast to a double. You can do that like so ([Example Code](http://ideone.com/uWg3p)):

```
Refurb_Rate = (double)totalRefurb / (double)totalUnits * 100d;
```

Otherwise, you need to change `Refurb_Rate` from a `double` to an `int`.

Comment: @FreeAslinBeer I tried all three ways and it still gives me the cannot convert to int error. It highlights return Refurb_Rate. Should I change my return type?

Answer (score 2):

You need to say that you want an int cast:

```
double a;
int b = (int) a;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

Refurb_Rate = (int)((double)totalRefurb / totalUnits * 100);

Make sure you case the int to double otherwise 1 / 2 will equal zero instead of .5

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand your error, because `Refurb_Rate` is a double and everything else is an int. However, I think what you really want is this:

```
if (totalUnits != 0)
    Refurb_Rate = totalRefurb * 100.0 / totalUnits;
```

Or possibly you want something like this:

```
int Refurb_Rate = 0;
...
if (totalUnits != 0)
    Refurb_Rate = totalRefurb * 100 / totalUnits;
```